# activity no longer starts

Tags: java, android, android-activity

recently my activity doesn't start anymore but the Toast.makeText is executed.
I can't make sense of the 4 lines of error message that comes.
Please help!

Main Activity:

```
        btn_new.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, new_txt, duration).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Neues_Protokoll.class));

            String Bauvorhaben = bauvorhaben.getText().toString();
            String Abschnitt = abschnitt.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Bauvorhaben", Bauvorhaben);
            intent.putExtra("Abschnitt", Abschnitt);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
```

Error message:

```
2022-11-15 17:20:52.141 25974-25974/com.example.jasinskibdv W/MirrorManager: this model don't Support
2022-11-15 17:20:52.226 25974-25974/com.example.jasinskibdv D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10045; state: ENABLED
2022-11-15 17:20:52.277 25974-25974/com.example.jasinskibdv D/DecorView[]: getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
2022-11-15 17:20:52.831 25974-26003/com.example.jasinskibdv D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb40000786faf3200 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb40000786fb01200
2022-11-15 17:21:21.414 25974-25989/com.example.jasinskibdv W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
btn_new.setOnClickListener(view -> {
 String Bauvorhaben = bauvorhaben.getText().toString();
 String Abschnitt = abschnitt.getText().toString();

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Neues_Protokoll.class);
myIntent.putExtra("Bauvorhaben", Bauvorhaben);
myIntent.putExtra("Abschnitt", Abschnitt);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
});
```

Comment: @FischerFritz If you find this is helpful and correct please upvote and accept , Thanks.